# Add additional column to temp table based on a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-query-store

I have three tables with no foreign keys between them. I need to get `count(*)` from all these 3 tables. I'm using `union` between these tables and able to the get the output as below.

```
Output:
10
20
15
```

However, I need to add additional column beside those rows specifying table names or LineOfBusiness. Can someone help me achieve this.

```
Expected Output:
10    Customer
20    Provider
15    Merchant
```

Comment: are looking for something like this: select count(*), 'Customer' as LOG from Customer union select count(*), 'Provider' as LOG from Provider union select count(*), 'Merchant' as LOG from Merchant ?

Comment: Please show us the code that got you the first results so we can help you modify it.

Comment: Here is the query and its output:


'select count(*) from DL_5000_5002 as RDC WHERE RDC.CallStatusZone1 in ('P')
union ALL
select count(*) from DL_5000_5003 as U WHERE U.CallStatusZone1 in ('P')
union ALL
select count(*) from DL_5005_5005 AS PM where PM.CallStatusZone1 in ('P')
union ALL
select count(*) from DL_5005_5006 AS PP where PP.CallStatusZone1 in ('P')'

**Output:**


1835
0
0
0

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot of missing information so i'm gonna go with what you've provided; in short, what you're asking is VERY SIMPLE. you simply just have to type the table name into the select statement like so:

```
select count(*) as Total, 'RDC' as TableName
from DL_5000_5002 as RDC
where RDC.CallStatusZone1 in ('P')

union all

select count(*) as Total, 'U' as TableName 
from DL_5000_5003 as U 
WHERE U.CallStatusZone1 in ('P') 

union all

select count(*) as Total, 'PM' as TableName
from DL_5005_5005 AS PM 
where PM.CallStatusZone1 in ('P') 

union all

select count(*) as Total, 'PP' as TableName
from DL_5005_5006 AS PP 
where PP.CallStatusZone1 in ('P')
```

now if you are wanting to pull those table names dynamically into another column or some other value based on conditions, then that's a whole other story.

the result set would be as follows:

```
Total       TableName
----------  ----------
1835        RDC
0           U
0           PM
0           PP
```